# why arguments object is not showing it's method in console

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this code:

```
var args;
function foo(){
  args = arguments;
}

foo();

console.log(args); // []
args.callee(); // foo
```

how come I'm not able to see any property or method of arguments object in console yet able to call callee method ?

Comment: Which console are you using? They're not all the same. There's no standard for console output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing `foo` any arguments.  Also, The `callee` property is "non-enumerable".

Comment: is there anyway i can create a non enumerable property or method in javascript ?

Comment: @niteshsharma: Have a look at [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Disclaimer: this assumes you're using the Chrome or Firebug consoles, there is no standard, so custom consoles might do funky things.</sub>

Because you used `console.log` which displays array-like* objects differently from "plain" objects. If you want to see the properties on the object, use `console.dir`.

<sub>* to be array-like the object has to have a `length` property and `splice` function, or a number of other niche conditions.</sub>

Comment: `arguments` doesn't have a `splice` function.

Comment: @Rocket, you're very right on that one, I can't recall all the specifics that consoles typically use to determine if an object is array-like. I *do* know that to get a custom object to be treated as "array-like" they have to have `length` and `splice`.

Comment: @nitesh: At least in Chrome, `console.dir` lists the `callee` property, if that's what you are after.